# Are there ethnically non-Chinese members of the CCP right now?

Tags: china, government, chinese-communist-party

Are there ethnically non-Chinese (non-Chinese ethnicities) members of the CCP (Chinese Communist Party) right now?

There are a few people like [Israel Epstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Epstein) who were members of the CCP, but as of now is there any other non-Chinese ethnics who are members of the CCP and play an important role within the CCP?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ethnic_groups_in_China

Comment: What is meaned by non-Chinese? Non-Han?

Comment: There are 6 ethnic groups who identify themselves as "Chinese", the term "non-Chinese ethnics" is quite confusing.

Comment: This question needs to clarify what is meant by "non-Chinese". At present, two of the three answers refer to people who are from ethnic groups considered to be Chinese by the Chinese government. I am voting to close until this issue is resolved.

Comment: CCP has [98M members](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/politics/article/3226150/chinas-communist-party-reaches-98-million-members-youth-membership-fell-due-strict-screening) so certainly yes, some of those 98M are officially non-Han Chinese.

Comment: "plays an important role within the CCP" could certainly be refined as well, e.g. Central Committee, National Congress of the Chinese Communist Party, or other roles. Or does it include those with non-official positions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some definitely exist, but they're few and far between. One that comes to mind is Li Yizu, a geologist of Caucasian descent. He was adopted by Han Chinese parents and brought up in Beijing. According to [a profile by China Global Television Network](https://news.cgtn.com/news/2021-06-28/The-Party-Profile-Geologist-Li-Yizu-11saDAOwx4A/index.html), he applied to join the CCP in 1966, but was not accepted until 1981.

> Biologically Li Yizu is a Caucasian, but culturally he is Chinese and politically he is a Communist Party member. He had faith and was motivated by the party when he was braving the cold to find coal in Xinjiang or teaching children about survival skills in the wild. Like many of his generation, he found something bigger than himself that is highly respected in Chinese society, to serve the people. That choice not only made him a successful man but also a proud member of the party.

Answer (score 12):

[There is an ethnic Kazakh in the new composition of the Central Committee of the Communist Party of China](https://newtimes.kz/obshchestvo/158517-v-novom-sostave-ck-kompartii-kitaya-sostave-est-etnicheskij-kazah)

> **There is an ethnic Kazakh in the new composition of the Central Committee of the Communist Party of China**
>
> In China, a new composition of the Central Committee of the Communist
> Party (CPC Central Committee) of 205 people has been elected. Among
> them is ethnic Kazakh Nurlan Abdimajin, "Express K" reports with
> reference to russian.people.com.cn.
>
> The members of the Central Committee of the Communist Party of China
> of the XX convocation were elected at the final meeting of the 20th
> National Congress of the CPC.
>
> The new composition of the Central Committee, the party's governing
> body, is elected for five years at the end of each congress.
>
> Nurlan Abdimajin was elected chairman of the Committee of the People's
> Political Consultative Council of China (CPPCC) of the Xinjiang Uygur
> Autonomous Region of China.
>
> It is known that Abdimajin was born in 1962 in Khorgos or the Kazakh
> Autonomous Region of the Xinjiang People's Republic of China. In 1985,
> he joined the Communist Party of China. Graduate of Beijing
> Pedagogical University. He worked in the judicial bodies of the
> People's Autonomous Republic of China, as well as in leading party and
> state positions of the Ili-Kazakh Autonomous Region and the People's
> Government of Xinjiang. Since 2008 — Member of the PC of the Politburo
> of the CPC of the People's Republic of China. Candidate for membership
> of the Central Committee of the Communist Party of China of the 18th
> convocation.
>
> Previously, this post was held by Askhat Kerimbai.

Comment: 据2020年人口普查数据，中国有152万哈萨克族，主要分布于新疆维吾尔自治区 - According to 2020 population census data, there are 1.52 million of Kazak in China, mainly spread around Xinjiang Uygur Autonomous Regions. Note that China considers Uygur its territory, and the Kazaks are considered an enthic minority of Chinese.

Answer (score 6):

There are a small number of non-Chinese ethnic minority members who belong to the Chinese Communist Party (CCP).

The most notable example is **Hu Chunhua**, an ethnic Hui Muslim who currently serves on the Politburo and is seen as a contender for Premier in the future. The Hui are one of China's largest Muslim ethnic minorities and number over 10 million people.

Other examples of non-Han members of the CCP leadership include:

• **Nur Bekri** - an ethnic Uyghur who served as governor of Xinjiang from 2008 to 2014 and is now vice chairman of the Chinese People's Political Consultative Conference.

• **Shohrat Zakir** - the current governor of Xinjiang and an ethnic Uyghur.

• **Tokhtakunov Töhtöröhun** - an ethnic Kazakh who serves as a member of the Chinese People's Political Consultative Conference.

• **Bu Xiaolin** - An ethnic Mongol who served as the director of the State Ethnic Affairs Commission and as a vice chairman of the Chinese People's Political Consultative Conference.

• **Bu Dongwei** - An ethnic Mongol who currently serves as the vice minister of justice.

• **Meng Jianzhu** - An ethnic Mongol who served as the minister of public security from 2008 to 2018.

• **Aihui** - An ethnic Tujia who currently serves as the vice chairman of the Hunan Provincial Committee of the Chinese People's Political Consultative Conference.

• **Dulamtseren** - An ethnic Mongol who currently serves as the vice chairman of the Inner Mongolia Autonomous Region Committee of the Chinese People's Political Consultative Conference.

• **Maral Tibet** - An ethnic Tibetan who currently serves as the vice chairwoman of the Tibet Autonomous Region Committee of the Chinese People's Political Consultative Conference.

These ethnic minority members within the CCP leadership remain a relatively small minority compared to the predominance of ethnic Han Chinese members and leaders.

Comment: 'Muslim' isn't an ethnicity.  You might want to consider rephrasing related to that.

Comment: Chinese ethnic minorities - Manchurian; Mongolian; Hui (Muslim); Tibetan; Miao (which includes the sub-group of Hmong, Hmu, Xong, and A-Hmao). Note the Chinese claim the territories where they live, and consider them the ethnic minority of Chinese.

Comment: @JimmyJames Tell that to "muslim by nationality" of Bosnia...

Comment: @alamar that the three predominant sociocultural groups in Bosnia are best identified by religion, and that the two Christian groups have nonreligious national ethnonyms, leaving the Muslim group to be identified by the unsatisfying "Muslim by nationality," does not imply that Muslim is an ethnicity.

Comment: Unsatisfying for whom? Bosnians and Hui are satisfied by their ethinc identity.

Comment: @alamar Nationality and ethnicity are not the same thing.

Comment: @JimmyJames and Hui is most certainly not a nationality, so the relevance of your statement is very tricky to ascertain

Comment: @Will But Hui is an ethnicity is it not?  I'm not sure where nationality came into the discussion.  Aren't all of these people of Chinese nationality?  I don't see anything in the question asking about religion so I'm not sure why it's relevant to note it for this one individual or describe an ethnicity as Muslim.

Comment: I am tired of the comments.

Comment: @user366312 Then don't post any.

Comment: @JimmyJames you seem to be confused about what an ethnicity is. It is not simply interchangeable with ancestry or any other sociological concept that precludes religion. You may have a personal preference not to define Hui Muslims by their religion but haven't explained why this particular perspective on ethnicity amounts to an improvement in the answer, which is the only reason you should be weighing in on the issue here in the first place.

Comment: @Will Ethnicity, nationality, and religion are 3 related but separate concepts.  There are Arab Jews and German Muslims and Han Christians.  If you aren't aware of this distinction, you should probably understand it before commenting on such things.  What evidence is there that Hu Chunhua is a Muslim?

Comment: @Will How does describing Hui as 'muslim' relate to the question at hand?  Why is it important to note?  If it's such a crucial detail, why isn't religion noted for the Uighur on the list?  Is it only important to note the 'Muslim ethnicities'?  What about everyone else?

Comment: @JimmyJames now that you've accepted that religion and ethnicity are related, it falls to you to demonstrate why you consider ancestry and not religion to be the only, or even the main, relevant feature of Hu's ethnic identity and so have a real improvement to the answer to put forward. If you don't know then you need to conduct this research somewhere else. I'm not an expert on ethnic groups in China, but I don't need to be to ask that you keep the comments below answers on-topic, whereas you do to weigh in on the answer's quality in this respect.

Comment: @Will It's pretty simple: this answer would be improved by removing the irrelevant reference to religion.  Unless you can explain to me why it's important to say Hui Muslim (especially for someone who doesn't seem to discuss what his religion is or if he has one) over just 'Hui', I can't figure out why you have an issue with this recommendation.

Comment: @JimmyJames it is absolutely not necessary to explain to someone learning for the first time how some ethnic groups are demarcated in order to decide whether a widely-referenced ethnic identity is appropriate to mention in an answer to a question about ethnicity.

Comment: @Will If it's so obviously correct that the Hui are a 'Muslim ethnicity' (a concept I reject for many reasons), why is it necessary to qualify them as such?  Is there a distinct non-Muslim Hui ethnicity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147140/discussion-between-will-and-jimmyjames).

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

- As of end 2022, 7.445 million of the 98.041 million CCP members (7.59%) were non-Han-Chinese; and
- In the 20th Central Committee (2022–27), 9 of the 205 members (4.39%) are non-Han-Chinese.

For comparison,

- In the 2020 Census, 8.89% of China's population were non-Han-Chinese.

---

Sources: [Gov.cn](https://www.gov.cn/yaowen/liebiao/202306/content_6889108.htm), [Voice of America](https://www.voachinese.com/a/china-s-ethnic-minorities-find-less-space-at-ccp-top-20221025/6804280.html), [Xinhua](http://www.xinhuanet.com/politics/2021-05/11/c_1127431323.htm).

("Non-Han-Chinese" = "Ethnic Minorities 少数民族" = Non-Han [ethnic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ethnic_groups_in_China) as officially classified by China.)